# ChromeOS volume keys not working for Apple Magic Trackpad 2

Tags: keyboard, google-chrome-os

The volume, brightness, audio control, etc. buttons all work fine when using the Apple Magic Keyboard 1 with ChromeOS.

However, if I plug in an Apple Magic Keyboard 2 (the one with TouchID) keyboard, the volume, brightness, audio, etc. controls are mapped incorrectly.

Is there a way to teach ChromeOS about the proper keys on the Magic Keyboard 2?

Comment: Very likely you'll need to way for proper support to be added to the kernel.

Comment: Can you better define "mapped incorrectly" ?

Comment: So for example, volume up seems to open the chrome dev panel, volume down maximizes windows.